# Why are there 0 questions?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

According to https://superuser.com/questions, there are currently 0 questions on Super User. https://meta.superuser.com/questions says the same about Meta Super User. The other tabs (featured, unanswered, etc.) are also affected.

The main pages (http://superuser.com and http://meta.superuser.com) display questions most of the time, but those questions are at least 55 minutes old right now; there are newer questions however.

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are working fine. All others sites seem to be affected.

Related: [All the sites currently have no questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166882)

Comment: More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166885/sites-tags-are-intermittently-devoid-of-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was transient during the migration between data centers.